# Mysql server installed but not running

Tags: installation, mysql

I tried to install mysql 5.6.12 using the following procedure

```
# Preconfiguration setup
shell> groupadd mysql
shell> useradd -r -g mysql mysql
# Beginning of source-build specific instructions
shell> tar zxvf mysql-VERSION.tar.gz
shell> cd mysql-VERSION
shell> cmake .
shell> make
shell> make install
# End of source-build specific instructions
# Postinstallation setup
shell> cd /usr/local/mysql
shell> chown -R mysql .
shell> chgrp -R mysql .
shell> scripts/mysql_install_db --user=mysql
shell> chown -R root .
shell> chown -R mysql data
# Next command is optional
shell> cp support-files/my-default.cnf /etc/my.cnf
shell> bin/mysqld_safe --user=mysql &
# Next command is optional
shell> cp support-files/mysql.server /etc/init.d/mysql.server
```

Source: [Installing MySQL Using a Standard Source Distribution][1]

Now the problem is

I did

```
 shell> /etc/init.d/mysql.server start

 *  Mysql is running
```

But when I do something like

```
 shell> mysql

 The program 'mysql' is currently not installed. You can install it my typing: apt-get install mysql-client-core-5.5
```

Now what should I do. Please Help.

Comment: Install the mysql client package. Just make sure that it's the same version as your server.

Comment: Is there a reason you are building mysql from source and using the one in the ubuntu repositories?

Answer (score 0):

To run MySQL from terminal, you have to have the Client package, as per you output above.  To install, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-client-core-5.5
```

Or

To install click [**MySQL database core client** [image: Install comixcursors-lefthanded]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/mysql-client-core-5.5/)

Answer (score 0):

It ought to have built the `mysql` client when you built and installed from source. To check, take a look in the `bin` directory inside the source directory that you did the build in. I am not sure where it would have installed to, though. You could try running `find / -name mysql -type f` to find it. Then look at whether that location is on your path (`echo $PATH`).